# Forms has no attribute form

Tags: django

Hi guys im new to django so i tried to import forms from django and use it to make a section to send out articles and this is the code :

```
from django import forms

class SendArticleForm(forms.form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    body = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    published_at = forms.DateField()
```

so after i tried to upload this code and run local server it gave me this error and i cant findout how this is happend.

- class SendArticleForm(forms.form):
  AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'form'

Comment: Capital F
use `forms.Form` instead of `forms.form` in `class SendArticleForm(forms.form):'.

Comment: @CC7052 WOW thank mate you made so easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Form` attribute of `froms` it goes like this:

```
from django import forms

class SendArticleForm(forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField()
```